# Kernal Panic IOAudioFamily second time within 20 days

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, kernel-panic

The first time:

I have not shut down the computer in about 2 weeks, always on sleep at night. Before I turned it to sleep, I used ScreenFlow and perhaps also checked my email. I just moved the computer from room  to room and waited about 30 minutes before turning it on.
I saw the log in screen for 1 second, and then it went to the gray screen.

Here is the problem description:

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  7434441 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          2
Anonymous UUID:                    my UUID

Mon Aug 25 19:10:02 2014
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff80223ede1a): "A kext releasing a(n) AppleHDAEngineOutput has corrupted the registry."@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2050.24.15/libkern/c++/OSObject.cpp:218
Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8112e4bd90 : 0xffffff802201d626 
0xffffff8112e4be00 : 0xffffff80223ede1a 
0xffffff8112e4be50 : 0xffffff7fa257a8c7 
0xffffff8112e4be70 : 0xffffff8022430536 
0xffffff8112e4beb0 : 0xffffff8022447501 
0xffffff8112e4bef0 : 0xffffff802243063b 
0xffffff8112e4bf30 : 0xffffff802242fa20 
0xffffff8112e4bf90 : 0xffffff802242fe17 
0xffffff8112e4bfb0 : 0xffffff80220b3137 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily(1.8.9f11)[AB8DD2DD-43BD-3B7B-95F7-26E6E0BBF339]@0xffffff7fa2579000->0xffffff7fa25aafff
            dependency: com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib(1.6)[E29D4200-5C5A-3A05-8A28-D3E26A985478]@0xffffff7fa2556000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
12E55

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 896CB1E3-AB79-3DF1-B595-549DFFDF3D36
Kernel slide:     0x0000000021e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8022000000
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 289626129667822
last loaded kext at 208576929916: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs   1.8.4 (addr 0xffffff7fa265c000, size 229376)
last unloaded kext at 910234754533: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI    5.2.5 (addr 0xffffff7fa29c0000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.eltima.ElmediaPlayer.kext   1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.3.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.3.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.3.6
net.telestream.driver.TelestreamAudio   1.0.4
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.8.4
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.87
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   8.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.7fc4
com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator  1.0.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.1.4f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.1.4f2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.3d0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.11
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.3d1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.4.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.1b4
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   615.20.17
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 74.5.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.1.4f2
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.1.4f2
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.11d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.5
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.7
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.3.0d51
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    8.1.2
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   8.1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 237.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.7.8
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   530.4
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220.3
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 345
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f4
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D48392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D48392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.4f2 12041, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS725050A9A362, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0245, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 7
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

I didn't care about it that much since it's been a few months since I had my last gray screen. However, about 2 weeks later, I had another gray screen. This time I started playing a youtube video, and about 2 seconds in, I unplugged my headphones to hear it on the speakers. Before I heard anything, the gray screen appeared.

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  446712 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1
Anonymous UUID:                    my UUID

Fri Sep 12 14:17:40 2014
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff80099ede1a): "A kext releasing a(n) AppleHDAEngineOutput has corrupted the registry."@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2050.24.15/libkern/c++/OSObject.cpp:218
Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80f1ccbd90 : 0xffffff800961d626 
0xffffff80f1ccbe00 : 0xffffff80099ede1a 
0xffffff80f1ccbe50 : 0xffffff7f89b7a8c7 
0xffffff80f1ccbe70 : 0xffffff8009a30536 
0xffffff80f1ccbeb0 : 0xffffff8009a47501 
0xffffff80f1ccbef0 : 0xffffff8009a3063b 
0xffffff80f1ccbf30 : 0xffffff8009a2fa20 
0xffffff80f1ccbf90 : 0xffffff8009a2fe17 
0xffffff80f1ccbfb0 : 0xffffff80096b3137 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily(1.8.9f11)[AB8DD2DD-43BD-3B7B-95F7-26E6E0BBF339]@0xffffff7f89b79000->0xffffff7f89baafff
            dependency: com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib(1.6)[E29D4200-5C5A-3A05-8A28-D3E26A985478]@0xffffff7f89b56000

BSD process 
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f4
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D48392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D48392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.4f2 12041, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS725050A9A362, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0245, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 6
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

They both contain the same Kernel Extensions in backtrace of `come.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily` and `com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib`.  Does anyone know what caused these problems and possibly how I can fix them?

Comment: Did you reset your SMC?

Comment: Hi buscar웃, I have not reset my SMC, should I? What do you think caused the problem? Will resetting the SMC do any damage or erase any data?

Comment: Nope, resenting the SMC will not do any damage, since it shows IOAudio, SMC might do that.