# iTerm2 cannot be opened even after SMC and PRAM resets

Tags: terminal, crash, bug, iterm, kernel

I got a gray screen due to "A kext releasing a(n) AppleHDAEngineOutput has corrupted the registry." Once the computer restarted, I cannot open iTerm2 anymore. A 1-lined terminal shows up without the prompt and then crashes with this report:

```
Process:         iTerm [402]
Path:            /Applications/iTerm 2.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm
Identifier:      net.sourceforge.iTerm
Version:         0.10 (0.10)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [254]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-27 23:41:49.970 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          8277629 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           30
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  6367051 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7
Anonymous UUID:                      [my anonymous UUID]

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000001f25000

VM Regions Near 0x1f25000:
    VM_ALLOCATE            0000000001f20000-0000000001f25000 [   20K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> mapped file            0000000001f25000-0000000001ff0000 [  812K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/Keyboard Layouts/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle/Contents/Resources/AppleKeyboardLayouts-L.dat
    mapped file            0000000001ff0000-0000000001ffa000 [   40K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.IntlDataCache.le.kbdx

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a215a97 memmove$VARIANT$sse42 + 218
1   iTerm                           0x14021aa0 -[VT100Screen setNewLine] + 192
2   iTerm                           0x1401e3c6 -[VT100Screen putToken:] + 4630
3   iTerm                           0x1402de3b -[PTYSession readTask:] + 267
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x953b45d3 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x97473326 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 395
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x943af04f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x943aea79 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 233
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x943d4826 __CFRunLoopRun + 934
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x943d401a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 378
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x943d3e8b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x90fd7f5a RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 242
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x90fd7cc9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 374
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x90fd7b44 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 88
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x938c093a _DPSNextEvent + 724
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x938c016c -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 119
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x938b65cc -[NSApplication run] + 855
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x938595f6 NSApplicationMain + 1053
18  net.sourceforge.iTerm           0x000023e2 _start + 216
19  net.sourceforge.iTerm           0x00002309 start + 41

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x954f10ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a22d0ac _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a22ce79 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a214d2a start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x954f19ae kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x97c93c71 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 993
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x97c937a9 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 53

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x954f10ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a22d0ac _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a22ce79 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a214d2a start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x954f10ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a22d0ac _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a22ce79 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a214d2a start_wqthread + 30

Thread 5:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x954f0be6 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x94418650 __CFSocketManager + 1632
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a22a5b7 _pthread_start + 344
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a214d4e thread_start + 34

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x954f10ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a22d0ac _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a22ce79 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a214d2a start_wqthread + 30

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x954f08e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a22f280 _pthread_cond_wait + 833
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a2b5095 pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x974749a4 -[NSCondition wait] + 274
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x9746ca0f -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 795
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x9746c65f -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 159
6   iTerm                           0x1401c038 -[PTYTask readTask:] + 120
7   iTerm                           0x1401bde2 -[PTYTask processRead] + 162
8   iTerm                           0x1401b3c8 -[TaskNotifier run] + 1080
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x97476448 -[NSThread main] + 45
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x974763cb __NSThread__main__ + 1396
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a22a5b7 _pthread_start + 344
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a214d4e thread_start + 34

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x01d3d006  ebx: 0x140219f7  ecx: 0x0000003a  edx: 0x001e80c0
  edi: 0x01d3cf40  esi: 0x01d3cf86  ebp: 0xbfffe178  esp: 0xbfffe170
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010206  eip: 0x9a215a97   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x01f25000
Logical CPU: 6

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x6ffe +net.sourceforge.iTerm (0.10 - 0.10) <FFC95F5E-59FC-AA00-279D-3720355165C8> /Applications/iTerm 2.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm
    0xe000 -    0x16fff +Growl (1) <E4F2317F-C9CE-44E6-DEE6-BF04B7443869> /Applications/iTerm 2.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Growl
   0x1e000 -    0x31fff +org.andymatuschak.Sparkle (1.5 Beta 6 - 313) <5DF2B8A3-560D-4500-6B85-4215644DE532> /Applications/iTerm 2.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
   0x3f000 -    0xeafff  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib (106) <041B3399-5033-3395-9A71-6693F3A33D94> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
  0x12e000 -   0x24dffb  com.apple.WebKit (8536 - 8536.30.1) <4A5E9136-681F-3AB1-AD69-B59F2B9126E7> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit
  0x2fe000 -   0xf93ff3  com.apple.WebCore (8536 - 8536.30.2) <D644997F-5F1A-34B4-AF32-DD427E9043E2> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore
 0x178a000 -  0x1797ff3  com.apple.Librarian (1.1 - 1) <68F8F983-5F16-3BA5-BDA7-1A5451CC02BB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Librarian.framework/Versions/A/Librarian
0x14000000 - 0x14079fef +iTerm (0.10 - 0.10) <849F4DA7-15A1-0321-ECC6-0B713069C47C> /Applications/iTerm 2.app/Contents/Frameworks/iTerm.framework/Versions/A/iTerm
0x8fe92000 - 0x8fec4e57  dyld (210.2.3) <23516BE4-29BE-350C-91C9-F36E7999F0F1> /usr/lib/dyld
0x90007000 - 0x90009fff  libdyld.dylib (210.2.3) <05D6FF2A-F09B-309D-95F7-7AF10259C707> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x9000c000 - 0x90104ff9  libsqlite3.dylib (138.1) <AD7C5914-35F0-37A3-9238-A29D2E26C755> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x90105000 - 0x90105fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (45 - 45) <677C4ACC-9D12-366F-8A87-B898AC806DD9> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
0x90106000 - 0x9011ffff  com.apple.Kerberos (2.0 - 1) <9BDE8F4D-DBC3-34D1-852C-898D3655A611> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
0x90122000 - 0x9016aff5  com.apple.opencl (2.2.19 - 2.2.19) <968DD067-49D0-3B71-A96B-B3579698D992> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
0x9016b000 - 0x90171fff  libGFXShared.dylib (8.9.2) <F3B0E66D-5C47-3A5A-A2CD-F0C58E8322C3> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
0x90328000 - 0x90397ffb  com.apple.Heimdal (3.0 - 2.0) <964D9952-B0F2-34F6-8265-1823C0D5EAB8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Versions/A/Heimdal
0x903e9000 - 0x903ecffc  libCoreVMClient.dylib (32.3) <35B63A60-DF0A-3FB3-ABB8-164B246A43CC> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x903ed000 - 0x90439fff  libcorecrypto.dylib (106.2) <20EBADBA-D6D6-36F0-AE80-168E9AF13DB6> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x90452000 - 0x9055dff7  libJP2.dylib (850) <3FFCEFA6-317A-34AF-8D99-AEBB017543C5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
0x9055e000 - 0x90567fff  com.apple.CommerceCore (1.0 - 26.1) <8C28115C-6EC1-316D-9237-F4FBCBB778C5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
0x90568000 - 0x90574ffa  com.apple.CrashReporterSupport (10.8.3 - 418) <03BC564E-35FE-384E-87D6-6E0C55DF16E3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/Versions/A/CrashReporterSupport
0x905b9000 - 0x905baffd  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 23) <E42347C0-2D3C-36A4-9200-757FFA61B388> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
0x905bb000 - 0x905bcfff  liblangid.dylib (116) <E13CC8C5-5034-320A-A210-41A2BDE4F846> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x905bd000 - 0x90639ff3  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 707.11) <F9BB5BBE-69D0-3309-8280-2303EB1DC455> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x908e9000 - 0x908f0fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (379.38.1) <4F164CA8-4A4F-3B27-B88A-0926E2FEB7D4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x90957000 - 0x9095aff7  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1) <437D76CD-6437-3B55-BE2C-A53508858256> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
0x90e26000 - 0x90e5cffb  com.apple.DebugSymbols (98 - 98) <9A9ADA0A-E487-3C8F-9998-286EE04C235A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DebugSymbols.framework/Versions/A/DebugSymbols
0x90e5d000 - 0x90e81fff  libJPEG.dylib (850) <36FEAB05-86C5-33B9-9DE9-5FAD8AEBA15F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
0x90f80000 - 0x91363fff  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.0 - 626.1) <ECC3F04F-C4B7-35BF-B10E-183B749DAB92> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
0x91364000 - 0x91397ffb  com.apple.GSS (3.0 - 2.0) <9566A96D-C296-3ABD-A12A-E274C81C0B25> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
0x91398000 - 0x9139bff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (30) <CE5DBDB4-0124-3E2B-9105-989DF98DD108> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x91439000 - 0x9152affc  libiconv.2.dylib (34) <B096A9B7-83A6-31B3-8D2F-87D91910BF4C> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x9152d000 - 0x915c5fff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (557.6 - 557.6) <8DEEED08-A4B3-3B08-8C2A-BDDBF005B43F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
0x915d4000 - 0x916a8ff3  com.apple.backup.framework (1.4.3 - 1.4.3) <6EA22ED3-BA18-3A37-AE05-5D6FDA3F372F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
0x916a9000 - 0x916affff  com.apple.print.framework.Print (8.0 - 258) <12AEAD24-6924-3923-9E4A-C5D21231E639> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
0x916b0000 - 0x916c5fff  com.apple.ImageCapture (8.0 - 8.0) <B8BD421F-D5A9-3FB4-8E89-AD5CFC0D4030> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
0x916c6000 - 0x91740ff7  com.apple.securityfoundation (6.0 - 55115.4) <A959B2F5-9D9D-3C93-A62A-7399594CF238> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
0x91741000 - 0x91761ffd  com.apple.ChunkingLibrary (2.0 - 133.3) <FA45EAE8-BB10-3AEE-9FDC-C0C3A533FF48> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/Versions/A/ChunkingLibrary
0x91762000 - 0x91979fff  com.apple.CoreData (106.1 - 407.7) <EC4B8297-8E01-3778-A8A4-E8747F91109D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
0x91c67000 - 0x91cbeff7  com.apple.ScalableUserInterface (1.0 - 1) <2B5E454B-BC49-3E85-B54D-1950397C448C> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ScalableUserInterface.framework/Versions/A/ScalableUserInterface
0x91cbf000 - 0x91cf0fff  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 184.4) <A31BB2CE-6965-3610-8B11-EA26EC6D7EEA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
0x91cf1000 - 0x91e4affb  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.9 - 1.9) <8BF022FC-C38A-34AA-8469-D98294094659> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x91e4b000 - 0x91e68fff  libCRFSuite.dylib (33) <C9D72D0C-871A-39A2-8AFB-682D11AE7D0D> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x92c1e000 - 0x92edeff3  com.apple.security (7.0 - 55179.13) <000FD8E9-D070-326A-B386-51314360FD5C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
0x92edf000 - 0x92eebff7  com.apple.NetAuth (4.0 - 4.0) <4983C4B8-9D95-3C4D-897E-07743326487E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
0x92eec000 - 0x92ef3ffb  libunwind.dylib (35.1) <E1E8D8B3-3C78-3AB1-B398-C180DC6DCF05> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x92f5f000 - 0x92f63fff  com.apple.OpenDirectory (10.8 - 151.10) <A1858D81-086F-3BF5-87E3-9B70409FFDF6> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
0x92f64000 - 0x93207ff3  com.apple.CoreImage (8.4.0 - 1.0.1) <C25B9EEC-4824-3088-BC08-2EA516C0728C> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage
0x93443000 - 0x93444fff  libquarantine.dylib (52.1) <094A1501-373E-3397-B632-8F7C5AC8EFD5> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
0x93445000 - 0x936b6ffb  com.apple.RawCamera.bundle (4.05 - 690) <1B2DF4B6-1229-36E3-86CF-5006E2A6DBB2> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RawCamera
0x936b7000 - 0x9371bff3  libstdc++.6.dylib (56) <F8FA490A-8F3C-3645-ABF5-78926CE9C62C> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x9375d000 - 0x94319ff3  com.apple.AppKit (6.8 - 1187.39) <ACA24416-D910-39B8-9387-52A6C6A561F8> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
0x94334000 - 0x94340ff8  libbz2.1.0.dylib (29) <7031A4C0-784A-3EAA-93DF-EA1F26CC9264> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x9439d000 - 0x94585ffb  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.8 - 744.19) <DDD3AA21-5B5F-3D8F-B137-AD95FCA89064> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x94586000 - 0x945d4ff3  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.12.2 - 1.12.2) <15B4EFFC-22D1-3517-BE8C-7947DAA24729> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
0x945d5000 - 0x945d9ffe  libcache.dylib (57) <834FDCA7-FE3B-33CC-A12A-E11E202477EC> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x945de000 - 0x94600fff  libc++abi.dylib (26) <3AAA8D55-F5F6-362B-BA3C-CCAF0D3C8E27> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x94601000 - 0x946ffff7  libFontParser.dylib (84.6) <7D3EB3CC-527E-3A74-816A-59CAFD2260A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
0x94700000 - 0x947e9ff7  libxml2.2.dylib (22.3) <015A4FA6-5BB9-3F95-AFB8-B9281E22685B> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x94f09000 - 0x94fb3fff  com.apple.LaunchServices (539.9 - 539.9) <C0E0CFFF-3714-3467-87DA-4A6F0AF1953B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
0x95274000 - 0x95277ff9  libCGXType.A.dylib (332) <07B59FCC-6229-37C2-9870-70A18E2C5598> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x95278000 - 0x95287fff  libGL.dylib (8.9.2) <1082B9A5-9AA3-35D4-968B-3A3FE15B1ED7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
0x95288000 - 0x95395ff3  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.2.1 - 850) <C964E877-660E-3482-ACF9-EC25DFEAF307> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
0x95396000 - 0x954a3057  libobjc.A.dylib (532.2) <FA455371-7395-3D58-A89B-D1520612D1BC> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x954a4000 - 0x954affff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60027) <8EE30FA5-AA8D-3FA6-AB0F-05DA8B0425D9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x954b0000 - 0x954b1fff  libdnsinfo.dylib (453.19) <3B523729-84A8-3D0B-B58C-3FC185060E67> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x954b2000 - 0x954dbfff  libxslt.1.dylib (11.3) <0DE17DAA-66FF-3195-AADB-347BEB5E2EFA> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x954dc000 - 0x954f6ffc  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2050.24.15) <9E58DCC0-D5FF-37E1-AA7F-F2206719E138> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x9553f000 - 0x95552ff9  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework (235.29 - 235.29) <451701B6-03CE-3F26-9FF0-92D8DA1467EE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
0x95569000 - 0x95575ffe  libkxld.dylib (2050.24.15) <BEC097B0-9D9A-3484-99DB-0F537E71963E> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x95576000 - 0x95576fff  libSystem.B.dylib (169.3) <81C58EAB-0E76-3EAB-BDFD-C5A6FE95536F> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x95649000 - 0x9594eff7  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1037.6 - 1037.6) <4DB4B0C9-1377-3062-BE0E-CD3326ACDAF0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
0x9594f000 - 0x959a6ff3  com.apple.HIServices (1.20 - 417) <B8410ABC-E0DB-31EB-B923-17F3B65B5F4C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
0x959a7000 - 0x959b0fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.5.2 - 2.5.2) <89822A83-B450-3363-8E9C-9B80CB4450B1> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x959b1000 - 0x959b1fff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.8 - vecLib 3.8) <908B8D40-3FB5-3047-B482-3DF95025ECFC> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x9614e000 - 0x96157ffd  com.apple.audio.SoundManager (4.0 - 4.0) <ABC5FE40-B222-36EB-9905-5C8C4BFD8C87> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonSound.framework/Versions/A/CarbonSound
0x96271000 - 0x962cbffb  com.apple.AE (645.6 - 645.6) <44556FF7-A869-399A-AEBB-F4E9263D9152> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
0x962cc000 - 0x9630eff7  libcups.2.dylib (327.6) <D994A44F-CCDD-3D40-B732-79CB88F45908> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
0x9630f000 - 0x9631fff2  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0) <875363E7-6D02-3229-A9DD-E5A5568A7D61> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
0x96320000 - 0x96320fff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.8 - Accelerate 1.8) <4EC0548E-3A3F-310D-A366-47B51D5B6398> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x963d9000 - 0x9645eff7  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <454E950F-291C-3E95-8F35-05CA0AD6B327> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
0x9645f000 - 0x96463fff  com.apple.CommonPanels (1.2.5 - 94) <6B3E7E53-7708-3DA2-8C50-59C2B4735DE1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
0x96464000 - 0x9681cffa  libLAPACK.dylib (1073.4) <9A6E5EAD-F2F2-3D5C-B655-2B536DB477F2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
0x9681d000 - 0x96820fff  com.apple.help (1.3.2 - 42) <AD7EB1F0-A068-3A2C-9D59-38E59CEC0D96> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
0x96955000 - 0x96956ffd  libunc.dylib (25) <58599CBF-E262-3CEA-AFE1-35560E0177DC> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
0x96957000 - 0x9697cff7  com.apple.CoreVideo (1.8 - 99.4) <A26DE896-32E0-3D5E-BA89-02AD23FA96B3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
0x969a3000 - 0x96a0bff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.1 - 755.24.1) <70DE925B-51E8-3C65-8928-FB49FD823D94> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x96a0c000 - 0x96a0dfff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (220.3) <C532F6A6-7E85-38F3-8660-EC1066DF67BE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x96a0e000 - 0x96b2affb  com.apple.desktopservices (1.7.4 - 1.7.4) <782D711D-7930-324A-9015-686C2F86DBA3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
0x96b2b000 - 0x96b34ff9  com.apple.CommonAuth (3.0 - 2.0) <34C4768C-EF8D-3DBA-AFB7-09148C8672DB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/Versions/A/CommonAuth
0x96c17000 - 0x96c65ffb  libFontRegistry.dylib (100) <3B8350C2-4D8F-38C4-A22E-2F855D7E83D1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
0x96c66000 - 0x96c92ff7  libsystem_info.dylib (406.17) <AA5611DB-A944-3072-B6BE-ACAB08689547> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x96f01000 - 0x96f01ffd  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit (1.9 - 1.9) <F7638E43-F885-372E-9DAE-24D0C21AA66E> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
0x96f02000 - 0x97344fff  com.apple.CoreGraphics (1.600.0 - 332) <67E70F21-A0F1-356F-90B7-4B90C468EE2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
... [the rest of this section can be found in the link below]
0x9a683000 - 0x9a68dfff  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework (4.1.5 - 4.1.5) <B855E8B4-2EE3-3BFF-8547-98A0F084F9AF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 3
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 156
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=141.1M resident=100.1M(71%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=41.0M(29%)
Writable regions: Total=164.6M written=16.7M(10%) resident=45.8M(28%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=118.8M(72%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
ATS (font support)                 31.9M
ATS (font support) (reserved)         4K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
CG backing stores                  7260K
CG image                             12K
CG raster data                      240K
CG shared images                   1184K
CoreServices                       2372K
MALLOC                             96.0M
MALLOC guard page                    48K
Memory tag=240                        4K
Memory tag=242                       12K
Memory tag=243                        4K
Memory tag=35                      7200K
Stack                              67.1M
VM_ALLOCATE                        16.1M
__DATA                             6360K
__DATA/__OBJC                       140K
__IMAGE                             528K
__IMPORT                             16K
__LINKEDIT                         37.8M
__OBJC                             1848K
__OBJC/__DATA                        28K
__PAGEZERO                            4K
__TEXT                            103.3M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                       121.0M
shared memory                       308K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             500.7M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space    500.6M

Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f4
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D48392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D48392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.4f2 12041, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS725050A9A362, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0245, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

I have reset the SMC and the PRAM. I have also ran and passed the 3-minute version Apple Hardware Test.  But after all that, iTerm2 still crashes.  I can open other apps fine, such as Terminal and Chrome.

Btw, [this is](http://pastebin.com/HvhEYZ7n) that middle chunk of the crash report that got too long for this stackexchange question.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the second time this month you've posted about kernel extensions corrupting the registry:

[Kernal Panic IOAudioFamily second time within 20 days](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145061/kernal-panic-ioaudiofamily-second-time-within-20-days)

I would be concerned that you have possible hardware issues as kernel panics and corrupted registry issues are definitely not the norm.

First step is to boot to Safe Mode to clear your system-/application caches and rebuild your font libs: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

If that doesn't take care of the issue, I would run hardware diagnostics to see whether that turns up any problems. If running quick diagnostics doesn't turn up anything, I'd run a full suite of comprehensive tests overnight. If the box reports hardware errors or kernel panics during testing, it should be taken to a Genius Bar or an authorized Apple repair centre for further tests and repair.

Comment: Hi Trane, Safe Mode and the extended hardware test didn't solve the problem or find any problems. I haven't found any other issue with my computer other than iTerm2. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I still recommend a Genius Bar visit to try to determine the cause. Kernel panics and issues with extensions are unusual and of significant concern.